# How can I access the elements of this matrix

Tags: c, matrix, data-structures

I found this question on code signal I have this struct how can I access the elements of this matrix

Arrays are already defined with this interface:

```
typedef struct arr_##name {
    int size;
    type *arr;
} arr_##name;

arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
    arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
    return a;
}

int solution(arr_arr_integer matrix) 
{}
```

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and show a [mre]? Apparently the type definition and allocation seem to be in a macro. -- However, do you know how to access an element of an array in principle, and how to access an element of a structure? Why do you think it is different in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 sections are part of a macro definition which uses a `name` argument.  You invoked that macro with the `name` of `arr_integer` to declare the type.

In the function `solution()` you would access the argument `matrix` with `matrix.size` and `matrix.arr`.

If the `matrix` is large, btw, you usually prefer to pass a pointer `int solution(arr_arr_integer *matrix)` instead of by value.

Comment: yeah i know that i have to use matrix.arr but how to access the matrix i mean how the expression would be ,arr is one pointer so i cant write *(*(matrix.arr+i)+j) to access the element

Comment: I would encourage you to update your question as it's not clear.  Also, you would need to us what type  `type` is.  To answer above it could be `matirx.arr[i * row_size][j]` or in pointer form `*(matrix.arr + i * row_sizes + j)`.